# Is it possible to create a nested array from a known node path? (PHP + SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, database, algorithm

possibly this question is stupidly trivial, but after hours of unsuccessful researching (perhaps my head is melt at this time and I'm unable to understand a single `$a = 1` assignation), I feel forced to seek for help...

I'm trying to figure out how to build a nested array (to build a navigable tree), given this result from a stored procedure:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RegionID | CountryID |  CityID   |  StoreID  |  RegionName   Country Name |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     1     |     1     |     1     |    Europe        Albania   |
|    1     |     1     |     2     |     2     |    Europe        Albania   |
|    1     |     2     |     3     |     3     |    Europe        Andorra   |
|    2     |     3     |     4     |     4     | North America    Canada    |
|   ...    |    ...    |    ...    |    ...    |                            | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Such array would follow this hierarchy:

Region > Country > City > Store

My first approach was to build this structure by making recursive queries on the different tables which store all the different equivalency IDs (e.g. fetch all countryIDs given a RegionID, and so on), filling a nested array and finally build up the `<ul>` structure.

But what I'm unable to guess is if I can build this hierarchy starting from a **single** query like the above one, concatenating the IDs (separated by a '-') as the path from the root (RegionID) down to the last leaves (StoreID).
Then I'd render the array in HTML as this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" data-node="1-1">Albania</a></li>
<li>
   <ul> 
   <li><a href="#" data-node="1-1-1">Tirana</a></li>
   <li>
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#" data-node="1-1-1-1">Store #1</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

More than expecting lines of code, got several questions:

1. Is this approach wrong? Naive? Inefficient? A total non-sense?

   Is this kind of result from the Stored Procedure the most suitable starting point to build a nested structure?

   Is this database following an obvious Adjacency list structure and I'm totally missing it?

   Any recommended readings for a non-engineer undergraduate to understand basic data structures and algorithms? (which it's what I think I'm lacking)

   I'm just over-complicating a pretty simple thing?

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using a recursive function to convert those data to HTML tree? I'm pretty sure that it is relatively simple

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I'm looking for. I'm just wondering if it's the most efficient way given my starting point, though.

Comment: I think it is: a single query on a dataset + an algorithm  whose space and time complexity are both O(N) ... it can't see a more optimized way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for pointing me the way. 
Finally, I've been able to build the tree using a recursive function, but I had to prepare first the data into different arrays. I'll post tomorrow the approach I tried, despite I'm still thinking it's not the best one.